# Deriving values for the Riemann zeta function on even natural numbers through recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, riemann-zeta

In [this](https://hanswisbrun.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/rm8256.pdf) paper, Yaglom shows an elementary derivation of the solution to the Basel problem by considering polynomials of the form
$$\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{2m+1}{2k+1}x^{m-k}$$
which has roots $$\displaystyle \cot^2\frac{k\pi}{2m+1},\,k=1,2,\ldots,m$$
For convenience of notation let $n=2m+1$. Using Vieta's relations, Yaglom shows that
$$\sum_{k=1}^m\cot^2\frac{k\pi}{n}=\frac{\binom{n}{3}}{\binom{n}{1}}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$$
Using the trig identity $1+\cot^2\theta=\csc^2\theta$, we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^m\csc^2\frac{k\pi}{n}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6}+\frac{n-1}{2}=\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{6}$$
Finally, using $\displaystyle\cot^2\theta<\frac{1}{\theta^2}<\csc^2\theta\,$ for $\theta\in (0,\pi/2)$, we get
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\frac{\pi^2}{6}<\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k^2}<\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
which gives us the desired solution. Yaglom suggests that this method can be extended via Newton's identities to produce values for the Riemann Zeta function on even natural numbers. If we call
$$p_j=\sum_{k=1}^m\cot^{2j}\frac{k\pi}{n}$$
then by Newton's identities we get the recurrence relation
$$k\binom{n}{2k+1}=\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{2(k-j)+1}p_j$$
Unfortunately I don't have much experience with recurrence relations, and I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be very much appreciated. My goal is to find and alternate expression for $p_j$, just as Yaglom found that
$$p_1=\frac{\binom{n}{3}}{\binom{n}{1}}$$

Edit: I'm specifically looking for a way to derive
$$\zeta(2k)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}B_{2k}(2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!}$$
using this method.

Comment: The introductory part is not really due to Yaglom [but to Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#The_proof) (*Cours d'Analyse*, 1821). Anyway, the idea is pretty clear: if we know a polynomial vanishing at $\cot^2\frac{k\pi}{n}$, we also know the power sums of its roots in terms of its coefficients and we are able to approximate $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{2m}}=\zeta(2m)$ with enough accuracy to get a closed form.

Comment: Here you just have to write down https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities in a explicit way: the elementary symmetric functions $e_m$ are given by the coefficients of the very first polynomial.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think if you write out Newton's identities, you get the recursion that i've written above for $p_j$, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: The same way you compute the power sums from the elementary symmetric function. Given $p_1=e_1$ and $e_2$, the above identity with $k=2$ provides $p_2$. Given $e_1,e_2,e_3$ and $p_1,p_2$, the above identity with $k=3$ provides $p_3$ and so on.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is there any way we could get a general expression for $p_j$?

Comment: As a determinant, sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressions_as_determinants (solve the system of equations given by the identity above for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ through Cramer's method. It will be clear).

Comment: I think my question may have been a bit vague, I've made an edit for clarification.